# Input date format changing by itself and I don't know why

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, date

I am writing API for filtering my data. In order to do filtering, I am adding filter inputs to the filter object which is initialized in my angularJs controller.

I am trying to get date value from HTML5 input date element with into that JS object. When I print that filter object, it seems like

```
{"date":"2018-11-14T21:00:00.000Z"}
```

But when I print the value of filter object to console,value of the date seems like;

```
{date: Wed Nov 14 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)}
```

The sample code which is giving the same result with my actual code :

```
    <html ng-app="MainModule">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<script>
        var MainModule = angular
            .module("MainModule", [])
            .controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope) {
                $scope.filter = {};
                $scope.write = function() {
                    console.log($scope.filter);
                }
});
</script>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="ali"> {{ali}}
    <input type="date" ng-model="filter.date">
        {{filter}}
        <button ng-click="write()">Write</button>
</body>


</html>
```

I am using Chrome browser but I tried to send filter object to the backend with Firefox but sended date value was same with Chrome's. How can I prevent my date value to be changed?

Comment: Note the `Z` postfix denotes Zulu time, which is equivalent to GMT+00:00. If I ran your snippet locally (I'm in GMT+08:00), I see `Wed Nov 14 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0800` logged to the console and `2018-11-13T16:00:00.000Z` in the HTML. These times are effectively equivalent.

Comment: Understood. Do you know how can I prevent my raw date data value to be changed? I want it to stay like "2018-11-14T21:00:00.000Z"

Comment: How are you sending `$scope.filter` to the server? If you're calling `JSON.stringify()` to serialise the data beforehand (like so—http://plnkr.co/edit/FdNrK5jtTYfYBe5xkNKi) the `Date` value should be in the Zulu time form.

Comment: I have other filter elements in filter object (like name, surname etc). I am sending it to server without doing any operations. E.g 
data: $scope.filter

Comment: Note that the console is not a reliable way of determining what the stringified version of an object is. You should call *toString* explicitly (e.g. here on SO `console.log(date)` is equivalent to `date.toISOString()` but in most browser consoles you'll get `date.toString()`, which is very different.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to say, I am sure that the date data going backend in same format. Returning backend error showing that.